# ubuntu 20.04, fail to lock after suspend

Tags: 20.04, unity, suspend, lock-screen

ubuntu `20.04`
kernel `5.4.0-77-generic`
`unity 7.5.0` desktop.

When I recover from suspend, it doens't show lock screen. Also, windows+L (I configured the shortcuts quite a bit, but whatever shortcut for locking the screen) doens't work any more.

Please don't ask why I use `unity` not `gnome`, or comment like `gnome` is better so use `gnome`. I need my desktop to be locked when I suspend it.

Comment: What display manager are you using?

Comment: Could you teach me how to check that? is `silverlight` the answer that you are looking for?

Comment: Run "cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager" and it should tell you. An example would be "/usr/bin/gdm3" if you had gdm3 as your display manager.

Comment: Thank you for that!
`/usr/sbin/lightdm` is the output of `cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager`.

Comment: It might work if you type the following into your terminal to reconfigure lightdm after the next reboot: "sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm"

If this doesn't work, then tell me. :)

Comment: Hi, I run the command, logged out, and logged back in again, but it doesn't work. It seems like Lock feature is completely disappeared

Comment: Hmm... Did you intentionally install lightdm and enable it in the past?

Comment: Yes. I was so upset when ubuntu changed the manager from unity to gnome, so I followed this (I think) to get it fixed. https://openschoolsolutions.org/why-i-will-use-unity-ubuntu-18-04/

Comment: Check to see if you have the Lightdm configuration file at /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf

Comment: `ls /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`
gives
`ls: cannot access '/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf': No such file or directory
`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131270/discussion-between-tom-and-alex-fullam).

Comment: Same problem here after I finally upgraded my ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04. I can't believe this is still an issue.

Comment: @amagard do you use HP computer?

Comment: No, I have an old Lenovo Thinkpad W520.